# nested loops in a menu

Tags: java, loops

i'm working on a project, it has a menu, i used (do,while and switch) main menu has a sub menu.

problem is sub menu dose not return to main menu

my work

```
case 4 : 
    do {
        int cho = in.nextInt();

        switch (cho) {

            case 1 :  break;
            case 2 : break;
            case 3 : break;
            case 4: break; // i want this to return back to main menu
        } // switch main 

    } while (choice !=4) ;// end sub 

 break;
```

When user enters 4 (sub menu)  it continues to loop the sub menu instead of returning

Comment: `break` breaks out of the `switch` and not the `do...while` loop. Just set `choice` to 4 to exit the loop or maybe,you wanted `cho` instead of `choice` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The break statements in your `switch` only break out of the switch. I'm not quite sure why this switch is even there. `choice` is never touched inside the `do...while` so it will never break. I would guess the solution would be to set `choice` to `in.nextInt()` instead of `cho`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cho` instead `choice`:

```
do {
    int cho = in.nextInt();

    switch (cho) {
       case 1 :  break;
       case 2 : break;
       case 3 : break;
       case 4: break; // i want this to return back to main menu
    } // switch main 
 } while (cho!=4) // Use cho instead choice
```